# localhost refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. how to solve this problem?

Tags: node.js

I'm getting started with node... it's just the basic thing still hits error when I try to go for https://localhost:3500/
here's the code--

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('lula by')

})
app.listen(3500, () => console.log('listening'));
```

Comment: Check 3500 port running in background if it is kill it and run your node

Comment: check ps aux |grep node ( for Linux) to see whether process is running on port 3500

Comment: add the error as well so it will be easier for us to answer.